# C++ programming return value handling

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing some c++ code here a function returns a value

```
int funcReturn()
{
return A->testvalue();  //for this de referencing i was getting error; 
                        //so i implemeted it this way
}
int funcReturn()
{

if (A!=NULL)
{
return A->testvalue();  //for this de referencing i was getting error; 
 }                       //so i implemeted it this way
}
```

Now the problem is that i need to have a counter part of else and also have to handle the else part in all the references ..

So can you please suggest what to do?

Comment: It was return only.. I miss typed it. The error is that i need to have the else part. And if i keep the else part. I need to handle that in all referencing parameters

Comment: If you don't want to handle that in all references then you can just call `exit()` in the `else` part inside the `funcReturn()` with some proper error message before calling `exit()`

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. As it stands here it's very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I don't think we're going to understand your question without a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: @GauravPathak exiting the program is not a good choice. I need some other solution

Comment: please don't vote negative atleast

Comment: @Mukesh: Downvoting is an expression of an opinion. The best way to change folk's opinion is to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the behaviour is *undefined* if `A` is `nullptr` (or `NULL` in C).

In the second case you are guarding against that, but then your helpful compiler is warning you that there is not an explicit `return` value on all program control paths.

You need to decide on the `int` value that ought to be returned if `A` is `nullptr`, and return that explicitly.

Comment: okay i return a int value. but i have to handle that value in all other referencing api's

Comment: and i don't want to do that

Comment: Well if your *certain* that `A` is never `nullptr` then you could use a run-time `assert` to that effect and then use `return A->testvalue();`. Else you're out of luck.

Comment: @Mukesh it will not handle itself.

Comment: Well then, if you can't *guarantee* that `A` is never `nullptr`, then you need to handle it. As @n.m. puts it so well.